# C# - How to use new features from 2017 in 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, enums, .net-micro-framework

I have both visual studio 2017 and 2012.
My project that I'm creating working only with VS2012 (I really don't know why, there are some additional installations that can be installed only on VS2012).

Here is part of my code.
For example:

```
enum Colors
{
 blue = 0,
 green = 1,
 red = 2,
} 

public Class LED
{
 private ComponentLED[] _arr;

 public LED() 
 {
   //Here I create the array and fill him with the objects.
 }

 private ComponentLED GetLEDObjectByColor(string color)
 {
   //This line don't work 
   //('System.Enum' does not contain a definition for 'Parse'
   int index = (int)( (Colors)Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), color) );
   return _arr[index];
 }
}
```

From what I understood: System.dll don't define some functions.
The only functions I see that works on Enum class are:
    Enum.Equals
    Enum.ReferenceEquals

So I thought the problem may be in the system.dll it's self.

Maybe you know what is the problem or how to solve it. I would very appreciate you.

Here some information about my current system.dll

Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft .NET Micro Framework\v4.2\Assemblies\le\System.dll

Runtime Version: v4.0.30319

Version: 4.2.0.0

and Application information:
Target Framework: .Net Micro FrameWork 4.2 (It's most - can't change it)

Comment: C# has had enums since the very beginning, there's something else wrong with your code.

Comment: I didn't said that c# don't have enums. But the only static functions they have in VS2012 are: Enum.ReferenceEquals and Enum.Equals

Comment: "I know that VS2012 is too old but for some reason it's the only version that works with my project." Well that's the thing you should fix, rather than permanently living with an ancient version. Note that there's no such thing as ".NET 4.2" so it's not clear what you really *are* targeting. And as Taylor says, that code should work with any version of desktop .NET anyway. I suggest you create a new question with details of your project, and what happens when you try to migrate it to VS2017. (If you really want to keep the current question, at least provide a [mcve] and say what error you see)

Comment: Thank for your remake. I Tried to make my question clearly.

Comment: Where did you get “my current system.dll Path” from? Why is it targeting `Microsoft .NET Micro Framework`? What kind of “project” are you building? ASP.NET? Windows Mobile? WPF?

Comment: It's special template (not something built-in VS like Console App or WPF). And this speical template supports only VS2012 and .Net Micro Framework 4.2

Comment: Right, now you've told us that it's the *micro* framework, that makes a huge difference - that's a very niche environment, and it would have been worth making that clear from the start. I'm not massively surprised that it doesn't just work out of the box with VS2017.

Comment: You might want to see https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/NET-Micro-Framework-44-Getting-Started-Guide that would at least help you with VS2015... not sure whether there's an equivalent for VS2017 though.

Comment: Check here: https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MVP-VisualStudio-Dev/About-NET-Micro-Framework-in-2017 for upgrade guidance to 2017, on a ported version of the .NET MF.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET MicroFramework is a very, very slimmed down version of the .NET framework that can run on embedded systems. In order to fit in the tight memory limits for these systems, a lot of features of the .NET base library have been stripped to leave the most important ones only. [The correct .NET MicroFramework system library guidance for enums can be found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc561845.aspx). And you'll see that it doesn't contain any Parse options.

In the case of your Color enum parsing, you'll probably have to implement your own code to do so based on the underlying int values. That will also make it much faster on these limited systems.

The .NET MicroFramework development slowed down considerably in the past years, but recently a new team has picked up development for it and ported it to Visual Studio 2017. A nice intro can [be found on Channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MVP-VisualStudio-Dev/About-NET-Micro-Framework-in-2017) and the code to build against 2017 can be tracked [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/NETMF/netmf-interpreter/issues/538).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
So the optimal solution would be...

```
private ComponentLED GetLEDObjectByColor(string color)
{
   if(Colors.blue.ToString() == color)
      return _arr[(int)Colors.blue];
  //And continue it until I passed all the enums... 
}
```